# Spring Boot - Replace Redis with MapSessionRepositiry in non persistance storage on clustered environment

Tags: spring-boot, session, redis

Requirement - I need to store high-volume user session data in spring boot. I tried Redis as an option but unfortunately, it got failed in a clustered environment.

I want to store the non-persistence session in a clustered environment in spring boot.

**Highly appreciated it if someone can share the git repo sample code. please help**

private FindByIndexNameSessionRepository sessionRepository;

how we can implement the FindByIndexNameSessionRepository in spring boot 2.6.3. i tried but got below error.

```
Description:

Field sessions in com.teknospire.switch_transaction.controller.login.Login required a bean of type 'org.springframework.session.FindByIndexNameSessionRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.session.FindByIndexNameSessionRepository' in your configuration.
```

```
@EnableSpringHttpSession
@Configuration
public class SpringHttpSessionConfig {

    @Bean
    public <S extends ExpiringSession> SessionRepositoryFilter<? extends ExpiringSession> springSessionRepositoryFilter(
            SessionRepository<S> sessionRepository, ServletContext servletContext) {
        SessionRepositoryFilter<S> sessionRepositoryFilter = new SessionRepositoryFilter<S>(sessionRepository);
        sessionRepositoryFilter.setServletContext(servletContext);
        return sessionRepositoryFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public MapSessionRepository sessionRepository() {
        return new MapSessionRepository(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
    }
}
```